# Use of integers and floating points

Tags: floating-point, int

Why does using float instead of int give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?

```
   {

  int a = 17, b = 5;
  int c =  a/b;
  cout<<c;

  }

  {

  float a = 17, b = 5;
  float c;
  c = a/b;
  cout<<c;
  }
```

Comment: They are different operations applied to data of different types. Why should they be the same? Any decent book on C or C++ will explain the difference between floating point and integer division.

Comment: @JohnColeman Could you suggest me any decent book on C or C++.

Comment: @vasanths294 For C I like "C Programming: A Modern Approach" by K.N. King. I don't have any recommendations for C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division performed by the / operator is different.

If both are integers,

```
c = a / b;
```

will do an integer division, so `17/5 --> 3`.

If both are doubles,

```
c = a / b;
```

will do a floating point division, so `17.0/5.0 --> 3.4`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about value. Float type variables keep their value as a float number even if you are assigning it an integer value. So if you are assigning ***17*** to a float variable, your variable will hold this value as ***17.0*** and does any operation according to the floating point.